# Java thread overlap

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, runnable

I'm having some trouble having more than 1 thread in the code. I get the error:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here is my code:

```
   public static void main( String args[] )
    {

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new server(1));
   t1.start();  

  Thread t2 = new Thread(new server(2));
   t2.start();  
   }
```

When the thread t2 code is commented out then it works fine.

Not too sure why I get that error, it doesn't make sense to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show code of `server` class

Comment: Are you trying to make both of them listen on the same port?

Comment: Yes same port service = new ServerSocket(5000);

Comment: So the first thread opens a socket on port 5000. The 2nd thread tries to open a socket on the same port, but that port is already in use by the first thread. The exception explained it perfectly.

Comment: You can't bind two `ServerSocket`s to the same address. It makes perfect sense once you start reading the documentation.

Comment: How would I make a thread to open a new socket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change your port for the second `ServerSocket` instance, since only one `ServerSocket` can be bound to the same port at the same time.

I suggest to improve your `server` class with something like this:

```
public class server {
  private static int port = 5000;

  public server(int yourParameter) {
    /*...*/
    service = new ServerSocket(port++);
    /*...*/
  }
}
```

This code will allow your servers to be bound to an always increasing port, starting from 5000.

Comment: I don't know, I just added it to the code since you provided a snippet in which I read `Thread t1 = new Thread(new server(1));`, and you provided an integer parameter to the `server()` constructor. It's just a name I gave to that parameter which I don't know what's for.